# How to fix this python code that performs login to website

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

am novice in python.Extracted below code to login to website from an online post, but getting error.

Please help to fix it and an explanation will help me

```
  import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    EMAIL = 'noob.python@gmail.com'
    PASSWORD = 'Dabc@123'
    URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/'
    c.get(URL)
    token = c.cookies['CsrfParam']
    # This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
    login_data = {loginCsrfParam:token, session_key:EMAIL, session_password:PASSWORD}
    # Authenticate
    r = c.post(URL, data=login_data)
    # Try accessing a page that requires you to be logged in
    r = c.get('https://www.linkedin.com/feed/')
    print r.content
```

Am stuck with below Error:

```
C:\Python27>python website.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "website.py", line 8, in <module>
    token = c.cookies['CsrfParam']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 329, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 400, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='CsrfParam', domain=None, path=None"
```

Comment: i am getting same error did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is that you're calling a value from a list which is empty. To call the first item in the list you say list[0]. In this case the list you're calling is empty so the first value doesn't exist hence the error.

I've ran your code and there is no @id value of 'recaptcha-token' which is why the code is returning an empty list. The only place a recaptcha token is needed is for signing up so I would suggest trying to log in without creating the authenticity_token.

Comment: Hi! I ran it with out token. It did not show any errors but it did not open the webpage either.I want this code to open the webpage and login with the credentials provided.

Comment: I've tried quite a few variations with requests now and I can't get it to work. From my experience Selenium tends to get round anti-programming systems so might want to look at this post: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-log-into-Quora-using-Python-since-they-dont-have-an-API . Alternatively there is a Quora module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/quora/ but this doesn't log in so it may not have the capabilities you need. Sorry I can't help more.